# nmcli authentification issue with bridged wifi hotspot

Tags: networkmanager

I'm currently trying to set up a wifi hostpot connection using `nmcli` that is connected to a bridge.

My bridge is set up using the commands:

```
nmcli conn add type bridge con-name br0 ifname br0
nmcli conn modify br0 ipv4.address [ip]/24
nmcli con modify br0 ipv4.method manual
nmcli con modify br0 bridge.stp no
nmcli con up br0
```

I'm currently using this to set up the wifi hotspot:

```
nmcli conn add type wifi master br0 con-name HOTSPOT ifname wlan0 wifi.mode ap wifi.ssid HOTSPOT wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk=HOTSPOT
```

The connection is able to be set up correctly; however, when attempting to connect, I keep getting prompted for the passkey over and over again.